# Format all numbers in a string with jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-formatting

I want this :

**"You won 50000000 dollars"** ==> **"You won 50,000,000 dollars"**

or

**"Can you jump 20000 times in 340000 meters?"** ==> **"Can you jump 20,000 times in 340,000 meters?"**

My solution is to split the words by space character and check all words separately. Is there a better way ?

Comment: no, that's how to format a number, i want a way to format all numbers in a string that i don't know count or numbers position in string...
first at all need to found out numbers and then use one of this codes.

Comment: That is what that function does as well. `"hello 10000 world 20000000 foo".replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");` => `"hello 10,000 world 20,000,000 foo"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split lines problem I often use here is a regular expression

```
input.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g,'$1 ')
```

But for your case it can Preobrazovatel in view

```
input.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g,'$1,')
```

I checked it out on this line

```
input=50000000
input.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g,'$1,')
```

The result was

```
"50,000,000"
```

that is, it works exactly as You need

Comment: that's work,
very very very thank you :)

Comment: I would be grateful if you put my answer as correct